# Bundler installs file with the wrong permission on deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, bundler

For some reasons the file of the gem random_unique_id end up with the wrong permissions when installed on deployment:

```
# ls -la /var/www/projectx/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/random_unique_id-0.2.0
total 48
drwxrwxr-x   5 projectx projectx 4096 May 26 23:36 .
drwxrwxr-x 148 projectx projectx 4096 May 26 23:36 ..
-rw-------   1 projectx projectx  320 May 26 23:36 Gemfile
drwxrwxr-x   2 projectx projectx 4096 May 26 23:36 gemfiles
-rw-------   1 projectx projectx  184 May 26 23:36 .gitignore
drwxrwxr-x   3 projectx projectx 4096 May 26 23:36 lib
-rw-------   1 projectx projectx 1067 May 26 23:36 LICENSE.txt
-rw-------   1 projectx projectx  223 May 26 23:36 Rakefile
-rw-------   1 projectx projectx 1000 May 26 23:36 random_unique_id.gemspec
-rw-------   1 projectx projectx 2934 May 26 23:36 README.md
drwxrwxr-x   2 projectx projectx 4096 May 26 23:36 test
-rw-------   1 projectx projectx  127 May 26 23:36 .travis.yml
```

They should be readable by all. Other gems have the right permissions:

```
# ls -la /var/www/projectx/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sorcery-0.8.5/
total 76
drwxrwxr-x   4 projectx projectx  4096 May 26 23:36 .
drwxrwxr-x 148 projectx projectx  4096 May 26 23:36 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 projectx projectx  5802 May 26 23:36 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-r--r--   1 projectx projectx    55 May 26 23:36 .document
-rw-r--r--   1 projectx projectx   733 May 26 23:36 Gemfile
-rw-r--r--   1 projectx projectx   503 May 26 23:36 Gemfile.rails4
-rw-r--r--   1 projectx projectx   865 May 26 23:36 .gitignore
drwxrwxr-x   4 projectx projectx  4096 May 26 23:36 lib
-rw-r--r--   1 projectx projectx  1083 May 26 23:36 LICENSE.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 projectx projectx   117 May 26 23:36 Rakefile
-rw-r--r--   1 projectx projectx 10309 May 26 23:36 README.md
-rw-r--r--   1 projectx projectx     8 May 26 23:36 .rspec
-rw-r--r--   1 projectx projectx  1309 May 26 23:36 sorcery.gemspec
drwxrwxr-x   8 projectx projectx  4096 May 26 23:36 spec
-rw-r--r--   1 projectx projectx   329 May 26 23:36 .travis.yml
-rw-r--r--   1 projectx projectx     5 May 26 23:36 VERSION
```

I'm installing these gems by using Bundler 1.6.2 and the Gemfile includes random_unique_id like this:

```
gem "random_unique_id", "~> 0.2.0"
```

I'm deploying using Capistrano 3.2.1 (Rake Version: 10.3.1) and capistrano-bundler 1.1.2. The generated bundle line looks like this:

```
cd /var/www/projectx/releases/20140526233202 && /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle install --binstubs /var/www/projectx/shared/bin --path /var/www/projectx/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet
```

Any ideas what can cause this issue?

Disclaimer: I wrote that gem, random_unique_id, but I don't see how that can have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really surprised by this, but permissions inside files for gems are not normalized, they are just copied from whatever permissions the developer had on their own files. All my files in my home directory were 0600 when I packaged that gem and those permissions were kept to people installing that gem.

I would consider this a bug, doesn't tar have an option to ignore file permissions? I'm not sure who to report this bug to though. Is it the ruby project? rubygems? gem? bundler?

I solved by releasing a new version of random_unique_id, v0.2.1, with better file permissions.